# How to properly position widgets with .pack in tkinker?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a project for my class in college, trying to make a tkinker GUI for something, but am having trouble getting the positioning right in it.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from sys import exit

def button_func():
        print("Test")

class TestClient(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()

        w = Listbox(width=20,height=24)
        w.insert(1,"WoW")
        w.pack(side=LEFT)
        w = Text(width=60)
        w.pack(side=LEFT)
        w = Listbox(width=20,height=24)
        w.insert(1,"Hi")
        w.pack(side=RIGHT)

        w = Button(self, text="Start", width=10,padx=10,pady=10, command=button_func)
        w.pack(side=LEFT)
        w = Button(self, text="Change Room", width=10,padx=10,pady=10, command=button_func)
        w.pack(side=LEFT)
        w = Button(self, text="Change Room", width=10,padx=10,pady=10, command=button_func)
        w.pack(side=LEFT)
        w = Button(self, text="FIGHT", width=10,padx=10,pady=10, command=button_func)
        w.pack(side=LEFT)
        w = Button(self, text="PvP FIGHT", width=10,padx=10,pady=10, command=button_func)
        w.pack(side=LEFT)
        w = Button(self, text="Loot", width=10,padx=10,pady=10, command=button_func)
        w.pack(side=LEFT)
        w = Button(self, text="Leave", width=10,padx=10,pady=10, command=button_func)
        w.pack(side=LEFT)

        stats = Listbox(width= 20)
        stats.insert(1,"health:")
        stats.pack(side=BOTTOM)

root = Tk()
root.title = "Test program"
tw = TestClient(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The problem is that I want the top buttons to be below the text and listbox widgets and the listbox labeled health to be below that, I'v tried packing them to top and bottom, but neither work and I can't find a soulution on google or here, does anyone know how i would go about this?

P.S. Sorry if the indentations bad, first time here and I wasn't sure how to paste the code without messing up the indentation.

Comment: I reccomend using grid rather than pack in this case. Have you tried that? PS you are also using the 'w' identifier for all your widgets, surley that can't be helping.

Comment: Ah Yeah, that was just a testing thing to start with i ment to change that before hand, I tried using grid before, but the text box and one of the list box's were the only thing that showed, maybe i could try it again.

Comment: look at self.grid_rowconfigure and self.grid_columnconfigure. From what you've said im guessing that you havent given each column/row a weight. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below for rough idea:

```
from tkinter import *
from sys import exit

def button_func():
        print("Test")

class TestClient(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()

        for n in range(3):
            self.grid_rowconfigure(n, weight=1)

        for n in range(8):
            self.grid_columnconfigure(n, weight=1)

        lb1 = Listbox(self, width=20,height=24)
        lb1.insert(1,"WoW")
        lb1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='news')

        t1 = Text(self, width=60)
        t1.grid(row=0, column=3, columnspan=3)

        lb2 = Listbox(self, width=20,height=24)
        lb2.insert(1,"Hi")
        lb2.grid(row=0, column=6, columnspan=2, sticky='news')


        b1 = Button(self, text="Start", width=10,padx=10,pady=10, command=button_func)
        b1.grid(row=1, column=0)

        b2 = Button(self, text="Change Room", width=10,padx=10,pady=10, command=button_func)
        b2.grid(row=1, column=1)

        b3 = Button(self, text="Change Room", width=10,padx=10,pady=10, command=button_func)
        b3.grid(row=1, column=3)

        b3 = Button(self, text="FIGHT", width=10,padx=10,pady=10, command=button_func)
        b3.grid(row=1, column=4)

        b4 = Button(self, text="PvP FIGHT", width=10,padx=10,pady=10, command=button_func)
        b4.grid(row=1, column=5)

        b5 = Button(self, text="Loot", width=10,padx=10,pady=10, command=button_func)
        b5.grid(row=1, column=6)

        b6 = Button(self, text="Leave", width=10,padx=10,pady=10, command=button_func)
        b6.grid(row=1, column=7)

        stats = Listbox(self, width= 20)
        stats.insert(1,"health:")
        stats.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=8, sticky='news')

root = Tk()
root.title = "Test program"
tw = TestClient(root)
root.mainloop()
```